# Trouble using std::make_unique with member variable of class

Tags: c++, c++14, smart-pointers, unique-ptr, class-members

I have not used `std::make_unique` before, and code inspection encouraged me to do it.

If I use this, it does not display errors:

```
auto x = make_unique<CChristianLifeMinistryHtmlView>();
```

But when I try it with my class member variable `CChristianLifeMinistryHtmlView *m_pHtmlPreview` it does not like it:

```
m_pHtmlPreview = std::make_unique<CChristianLifeMinistryHtmlView>();
```

How do I use `std::make_unique` with a member variable of the class?

Comment: This nothing to do with member, if you try `CChristianLifeMinistryHtmlView *x = make_unique<CChristianLifeMinistryHtmlView>();` you will have exactly the same issue

Comment: You need to use `std::unique_ptr<CllassToBeUsed>`, but it seems you learn it backward. First you should understand what smart pointers are.

Comment: `std::shared_ptr` has counter, `std::unique_ptr` provides unique ownership hence it's name. Ithink you need to understand them first instead of blindly replace raw pointer with smart one. They are not that complex but need understanding to use properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your issue is nothing to do with the class member, rather its type!

[`std::make_unique()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique) returns `std::unique_ptr` for the template type `T` (i.e. `std::unique_ptr` of an instance of type `T`)

```
template< class T, class... Args >
unique_ptr<T> make_unique( Args&&... args );
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The member

```
CChristianLifeMinistryHtmlView *m_pHtmlPreview;
```

is a pointer to a `CChristianLifeMinistryHtmlView`, not a `std::unique_ptr`. Hence, the type mismatch.

---

> How do I use `make_unique` with a member variable of the class?

Therefore, you need to use `std::unique_ptr<CChristianLifeMinistryHtmlView>` as the type of the `m_pHtmlPreview` member:

```
std::unique_ptr<CChristianLifeMinistryHtmlView> m_pHtmlPreview; 
...
m_pHtmlPreview = std::make_unique<CChristianLifeMinistryHtmlView>();
```

---

If it is a long typing, a type alias wouldn't be a bad idea:

```
using UniqueCLMHView = std::unique_ptr<CChristianLifeMinistryHtmlView>;
UniqueCLMHView m_pHtmlPreview; 
...
m_pHtmlPreview = std::make_unique<CChristianLifeMinistryHtmlView>();
```